# Dynamic Combobox isselected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox that has the period of the day as its items. I am trying to make the isSelected item based on the period on the day through the use of a converter but for some reason my code won't work.

Below is my xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <staticData:SelectedPeriodConverter  x:Key="SelectedPeriodConverter"/>  
</Window.Resources>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,7" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="PeriodPicker" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" SelectedItem="PM">

    <ComboBoxItem>AM</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>PM</ComboBoxItem>

    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SelectedPeriodConverter}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ComboBoxItem.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

and my c# code for the converter is as follows:

```
public class SelectedPeriodConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string test = values.ToString();

        if (test == DateTime.Now.ToString("tt"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return value;
    }
}
```

The weird thing is is if I change isSelected to IsEnable it will trigger but otherwise it won't.

Another way I tried was to have the styling in the Windows resources.

This worked if I targetted comboboxitem but would not work if I added an x:class and used ItemContainerStyle to isolate the trigger to one combobox as I did not want it working on all the comboboxes I had in my form.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SelectedPeriodConverter}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<ComboBox Grid.Column="4" Margin="0,7" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="PeriodPicker" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" SelectedItem="PM">
    <ComboBoxItem>AM</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>PM</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

thanks Callum

Answer (score 0):

The fix was quiet simple.

Inserting the second code inside ComboBox.Resources tags instead of Windows.Resources tags worked for me like so:

```
<ComboBox.Resources>
                            <staticData:SelectedPeriodConverter  x:Key="SelectedPeriodConverter"/>

                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type  ComboBoxItem}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource SelectedPeriodConverter}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>



                        </ComboBox.Resources>
```

thanks Callum